# What was Littlewood's quip about Hardy and plagiarism?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, mathematics-social-history

I'm searching for a quote by Littlewood about Hardy not giving proper credit. The story (as I remember it) is that Littlewood claimed uncredited authorship of something Hardy wrote, Hardy claimed it was trivial, and Littlewood made some analogy to the interactions between oppressors and oppressed. The analogy is what Im looking for.

Ive searched quotes from Littlewood's Miscellany and A Mathematician's Apology to no avail.

Maybe it's connected to (but different from) this quote:

> I read in the proof sheets of Hardy on Ramanujan: “As someone said, each of the positive integers was one of his personal friends.” My reaction was, “I wonder who said that; I wish I had.” In the next proof-sheets I read (what now stands), “It was Littlewood who said…”. What had happened was that Hardy had received the remark in silence and with poker face, and I wrote it off as a dud. - Littlewood